# Facebook authentication through express server for Unity3D application

Tags: node.js, express, unity-game-engine, passport.js

I want to use express server with passport-facebook to authenticate facebook users. the client side is Unity3D application. I have no problem authenticating users if it was javascript client, since if the authentication was successful, it redirects to the index page. However, since I'm using Unity3D as client, I was wondering what will be the redirect function.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to implement this myself yet, but I was just reading about it.

You are gonna have to use the [Facebook Unity SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/) and login in the unity app. The SDK provides all the functionality you would expect. As for using the authentication in Express, you would be implementing somewhat of a Reverse OAuth Flow. I don't believe Facebook wants your app doing this, but once authenticated in Unity you could send the temporary access tokens to the Express API at which point you should be able to use the Node.js Facebook SDK.